# Trying to use R nparLD to test for between group variation in repeated measures

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, nonparametric

I am trying to determine if my subjects differ for a specific variable by sex. I have tried using nparLD but it only tests if my individuals differ between trials, not if there is variation between the sexes.

Here's what I've been trying to run:

nparLD(lowfreq~Sex,data=df, subject=Individual)

I have 2 sexes and 3 trials per individual with 45 individuals and 135 obs. total. It keeps trying to multiply sex by individual and says that it doesn't equal 135. How can I run this test to look for differences between sexes instead of between trials?

Example data

| Sex | Individual | Variable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F | F1 | 1.5 |
| F | F1 | 2.6 |
| F | F1 | 1.8 |
| M | M1 | 4.2 |
| M | M1 | 3.4 |
| M | M1 | 3.0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have equal number of observations (time variable) for each of the individual. I am first showing how it works with a dummy data, and below reproduce your error.
I am creating a dummy dataset for 14 subjects with two time periods.

```
data <- expand.grid(id = c(1:14), time = c(1:2))
#add sex
data[, sex := sample(c(0,1), nrow(data), replace = T)]
#add outcome variable
data[, var := sample(c(0,1000), nrow(data), replace = T) ]
# the following estimation works 
nparLD(var~sex, data = data, subject = "id")
```

```
Sample result below
Wald-Type Statistc (WTS):
     Statistic df   p-value
sex 0.02628156  1 0.8712146
```

Now suppose that you have one missing value for one of the observations for a subject ids

```
 nparLD(var~sex, data = data[c(1:27)], subject = "id")
```

You will receive the same error

```
Error in ld.f1(dat2[, 1], dat2[, 2], subject = dat2[, 3], time.name = nadat2[2],  : 
  Number of levels of subject (14) times number of levels of time (2) 
        is not equal to the total number of observations (27).
```

Comment: Hi Vivek, Thank you for this feedback! I think the issue is because I have three observations from each individual, but only 2 sexes. 3 x 45 is 135, which is my total number, but I need it to compare the sexes, so it keeps trying to multiple 2x45, which of course doesn't equal my number of observations. None of the observations are missing values, it's just trying to detect the wrong differences. Am I coding it incorrectly?

Comment: @michellemoyah That is correct. You have nested structure. Therefore you need to use the following : nparLD(resp~round*sex, data=tree, subject="subject", 
description=FALSE). You will get coeff for sex and an interaction. If you don't want to do that then take the averages by aggregating. I will edit the answer. Please accept if it helps.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you!!